# Can't flash stock rom - cache - partition table issue

Tags: android, rom, custom-rom, android-rom

So I tried to flash LineageOS on a Redmi 8, and while doing this I had an issue. It fails to mount cache (`Skipping mounting /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/cache`) then a few other errors related to cache not being there and then failed to set up expected mounts for install, aborting So, `adb shell ls dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/` - there is no cache img there.

Alright, I'll flash back to stock. Downloading stock I run `flash_all.sh` and then...

```
product: olive

Erasing 'boot'                                     OKAY [  0.009s]

Finished. Total time: 0.012s

Sending 'modem' (131072 KB)                        OKAY [  4.488s]

Writing 'modem'                                    OKAY [  0.779s]

Finished. Total time: 5.276s

Sending 'sbl1' (399 KB)                            OKAY [  0.016s]

Writing 'sbl1'                                     OKAY [  0.007s]

Finished. Total time: 0.032s

Sending 'sbl1bak' (399 KB)                         OKAY [  0.016s]

Writing 'sbl1bak'                                  OKAY [  0.006s]

Finished. Total time: 0.031s

Sending 'rpm' (165 KB)                             OKAY [  0.009s]

Writing 'rpm'                                      OKAY [  0.006s]

Finished. Total time: 0.024s

Sending 'rpmbak' (165 KB)                          OKAY [  0.009s]

Writing 'rpmbak'                                   OKAY [  0.006s]

Finished. Total time: 0.023s

Sending 'tz' (1491 KB)                             OKAY [  0.048s]

Writing 'tz'                                       OKAY [  0.010s]

Finished. Total time: 0.070s

Sending 'tzbak' (1491 KB)                          OKAY [  0.050s]

Writing 'tzbak'                                    OKAY [  0.010s]

Finished. Total time: 0.069s

Sending 'devcfg' (37 KB)                           OKAY [  0.005s]

Writing 'devcfg'                                   OKAY [  0.003s]

Finished. Total time: 0.017s

Sending 'devcfgbak' (37 KB)                        OKAY [  0.005s]

Writing 'devcfgbak'                                OKAY [  0.003s]

Finished. Total time: 0.017s

Sending 'dsp' (16384 KB)                           OKAY [  0.539s]

Writing 'dsp'                                      OKAY [  0.090s]

Finished. Total time: 0.638s

Sending 'dspbak' (16384 KB)                        OKAY [  0.518s]

Writing 'dspbak'                                   OKAY [  0.070s]

Finished. Total time: 0.597s

Sending 'sec' (0 KB)                               OKAY [  0.004s]

Writing 'sec'                                      OKAY [  0.003s]

Finished. Total time: 0.016s

Sending 'splash' (1239 KB)                         OKAY [  0.042s]

Writing 'splash'                                   OKAY [  0.009s]

Finished. Total time: 0.060s

Sending 'aboot' (761 KB)                           OKAY [  0.027s]

Writing 'aboot'                                    OKAY [  0.008s]

Finished. Total time: 0.044s

Sending 'abootbak' (761 KB)                        OKAY [  0.027s]

Writing 'abootbak'                                 OKAY [  0.008s]

Finished. Total time: 0.044s

Sending 'boot' (65536 KB)                          OKAY [  2.321s]

Writing 'boot'                                     OKAY [  0.315s]

Finished. Total time: 2.645s

Sending 'dtbo' (8192 KB)                           OKAY [  0.279s]

Writing 'dtbo'                                     OKAY [  0.037s]

Finished. Total time: 0.325s

Sending 'dtbobak' (8192 KB)                        OKAY [  0.260s]

Writing 'dtbobak'                                  OKAY [  0.037s]

Finished. Total time: 0.307s

Sending 'vbmeta' (4 KB)                            OKAY [  0.004s]

Writing 'vbmeta'                                   OKAY [  0.003s]

Finished. Total time: 0.016s

Sending 'vbmetabak' (4 KB)                         OKAY [  0.004s]

Writing 'vbmetabak'                                OKAY [  0.003s]

Finished. Total time: 0.016s

Sending 'recovery' (65536 KB)                      OKAY [  2.296s]

Writing 'recovery'                                 OKAY [  0.346s]

Finished. Total time: 2.651s

Sending sparse 'system' 1/8 (515428 KB)            OKAY [ 18.027s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  2.492s]

Sending sparse 'system' 2/8 (513944 KB)            OKAY [ 18.034s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  2.515s]

Sending sparse 'system' 3/8 (515076 KB)            OKAY [ 18.151s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  2.488s]

Sending sparse 'system' 4/8 (516208 KB)            OKAY [ 18.258s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  2.524s]

Sending sparse 'system' 5/8 (516208 KB)            OKAY [ 18.171s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  2.496s]

Sending sparse 'system' 6/8 (516208 KB)            OKAY [ 18.144s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  2.462s]

Sending sparse 'system' 7/8 (513944 KB)            OKAY [ 18.154s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  2.421s]

Sending sparse 'system' 8/8 (288476 KB)            OKAY [ 10.188s]

Writing 'system'                                   OKAY [  1.366s]

Finished. Total time: 155.914s

Sending sparse 'vendor' 1/3 (517164 KB)            OKAY [ 17.979s]

Writing 'vendor'                                   OKAY [  2.432s]

Sending sparse 'vendor' 2/3 (515456 KB)            OKAY [ 18.127s]

Writing 'vendor'                                   OKAY [  2.427s]

Sending sparse 'vendor' 3/3 (197240 KB)            OKAY [  6.927s]

Writing 'vendor'                                   OKAY [  0.927s]

Finished. Total time: 48.827s

Warning: skip copying cache image avb footer due to sparse image.

Sending 'cache' (152 KB)                           OKAY [  0.008s]

Writing 'cache'                                    FAILED (remote: 'partition table doesn't exist')

fastboot: error: Command failed

Flash cache error
```

Again the cache fails. No partition? Huh?

If it can help give pointers...

[image]

[image]

I'd be very thankful for any help!

Comment: Please read info at android tag